# Remove white border around div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a page that detects wether a mobile device is in portrait mode. The functionality seems to work properly, but there's something wrong with the layout. 
I keep getting a white border around my div-tag and I can't seem to figure out where it comes from. I checked the Developers Tools and found nothing. Setting the border to 0 didn't work either. Tried to work with overflow: hidden, nada.

http://jsfiddle.net/6c4e00x0/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="modal">
    <div>
        <div id="icon">
            <img id="rotate" />
        </div>

        <div id="msg"> 
            <a id="close" href="#">close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#rotate {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:url("http://m.campolympia.com/assets/mobile/site-images/icon-horizontal.png") center center no-repeat;
}

#msg{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

a {
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see anything instead of red background in your fiddle..

Comment: I checked fiddle as well, looks like you've just got a red background @ 100%

Comment: I couldn't see this either but you may want to try `outline: none;` on your divs css

Comment: Or this `<body style="margin:0;">`

Comment: Oh, the fiddle messed up my width. If you adjust the width to a smaller screen where the height is larger than the width, you should see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use are using `img` incorrectly. Replace `img` with a `div`.

`img` should be used like so with an image:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c4e00x0/9/)

**Note:** *Anyone seeing a red page has the window too small or big, the jQuery is what causes that.*

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
#msg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#rotate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("http://m.campolympia.com/assets/mobile/site-images/icon-horizontal.png") center center no-repeat;
}
img {}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div>
    <div id="icon">
      <div id="rotate"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="msg"> <a id="close" href="#">close</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

---

Since people cant seem to see it here is the before and after my fix.

[image: Before]

As you can see there is a border like the OP says.

[image: After]

And now we change the `img` to a `div` so it can correctly display. No border.

Comment: That's true. But fixing the image won't (probably) fix the (non-reproducible) white border around a div.

Comment: @Oriol I wouldn't put it as an answer if it doesn't. This fixes the problem, the image is being set in width and height with no image, as `img` images are define in the html as `src`. Also it is reproducible as I can see the white border, you have to size your window correctly.

Comment: I agree with Ruddy. The border is gone, so it fixes my problem. Thanks!